# Programming Arduino in C, will Interrupt Vectors work?

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, avr

I got Arduino to play with... but the Arduino language and IDE feel like a kids' toys to me.

So I'd like to use regular C to program it.

As I understand it, the bootloader sits in some place of the memory, has a `rjmp` in the reset vector, and when done, returns control to the installed "sketch".

The question is: What can I do in the "sketch" safely?

This is my current idea of what it looks like in the AVR with Arduino Bootloader, but it's maybe wrong:

```
.CSEG
.ORG 0000
rjmp bootloader
; ??? Interrupt vectors here
; ??? Interrupt vectors here
; Maybe it all goes to bootloader and it then forwards
;   it to handlers in the "sketch"?

bootloader:
; ??? some magic tricks here 
rjmp sketch

sketch:
; "Sketch" code
; I want my own interrupt vectors, too!
end:
rjmp end;
```

I mean, obviously the Bootloader uses some other parts of the AVR for it's function, so it'll have it's own interrupt handlers etc. If I use those in my program, will they work as expected?

So, what are the gotchas of programming Arduino with C (or even assembler)?

Comment: The bootloader lives in the upper flash and will not interfere with your code. You can use all the interrupt vectors. For programming the Arduino in plain C you just have to take a look at the documentation of the [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/), which comes with the Arduino environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVR devices with bootloader support have *two* sets of interrupt vectors, one for the bootloader (at the beginning of the bootloader section) and one for the regular firmware (at address 0). The BOOTRST fuse determines which reset vector is used by default, and `IVSEL` in `MCUCR` (or the equivalent in the device) determines which set is currently active.

Note that the lock bits can restrict which sets can be used, and as always see the datasheet for full details.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. Arduino is just a Library. If You look at source code the `setup()` and `loop()` funtions are inserted to `int main()`; The `setup()` just before infinite `while(true)` loop.

Comment: I am not talking about that, but whether the bootloader won't interfere with my program. But apparently it's somehow separated from the rest of the code.